# RSpec fixtures not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am taking over a code base and am trying to run the tests. I am
somewhat new to RSpec so this might be a trivial problem.

Basically I can tell that the fixtures are not getting loaded. All 100
tests fail with a similar error.

But I don't know why.  Below is the code. Where can I start looking?

In spec_helper.rb, which I know is running, I see:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.global_fixtures = :all
end
```

One of the tests in spec/controllers/downloads_controller_spec.rb
is below. I know it is running and I know that before the 'describe',
`Partner.count == 0`, so no fixture.

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe DownloadsController do
  integrate_views

  describe "when PDF is ready" do
    before(:each) do
      @registrant = Factory.create(:step_5_registrant)
      stub(@registrant).merge_pdf { `touch #{@registrant.pdf_file_path}`
}
      @registrant.generate_pdf
      @registrant.save!
    end

    it "provides a link to download the PDF" do
      get :show, :registrant_id => @registrant.to_param
      assert_not_nil assigns[:registrant]
      assert_response :success
      assert_template "show"
      assert_select "span.button a[target=_blank]"
      assert_select "span.button a[onclick]"
    end

    after(:each) do
      `rm #{@registrant.pdf_file_path}`
    end
  end
```

And here is what in various directories:

```
spec/fixtures/partners.yml - which contains 2 yaml records:

sponsor:
  id: 1
  username: rtv
  email: rocky@example.com
  crypted_password:
"c8e5b51b237344fe0e72539af0cac7197f094a5e933ffacf6e7fa612363c5933f520710c6427ac31fc4c68a2d7bb48eae601c74b96e7838f9ca1a0740b67576a"
  password_salt: "Y4PPzYx2ert3vC0OhEMo"
  name: Rocky
  organization: Rock The Vote
  url: http://rockthevote.com
  address: 123 Wherever
  city: Washington
  state_id: 9
  zip_code: 20001
  phone: 555-555-1234
  survey_question_1_en: "What school did you go to?"
  survey_question_2_en: "What is your favorite musical group?"
  created_at: <%= Time.now %>
  updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
# TODO: remove partner 2 in production
partner:
  id: 2
  username: bull_winkle
  email: bull_winkle@example.com
  crypted_password:
"c8e5b51b237344fe0e72539af0cac7197f094a5e933ffacf6e7fa612363c5933f520710c6427ac31fc4c68a2d7bb48eae601c74b96e7838f9ca1a0740b67576a"
  password_salt: "Y4PPzYx2ert3vC0OhEMo"
  name: Bullwinkle
  organization: Bullwinkle, Inc.
  url: http://example.com
  address: 123 Wherever
  city: Washington
  state_id: 9
  zip_code: 20001
  phone: 555-555-1234
  survey_question_1_en: "What school did you go to?"
  survey_question_2_en: "What is your favorite musical group?"
  created_at: <%= Time.now %>
  updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is done automatically now and you have solved it, but have you checked that your "spec/spec_helper.rb" contains:

```
# Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

Cheers